# ggpredict produces flat fit line for glmmTMB model

Tags: predictive-models, poisson-regression, glmmtmb

I am conducting a step selection analysis of animal movement data using a Poisson model in glmmTMB. The model runs as expected, however, when I use ggeffects to plot model predictions I get a flat line.

Step selection analyses compare the environmental covariates of "used" animal locations, i.e. the GPS locations recorded by their GPS collars, to "available" locations, somewhat randomly generated  locations, to evaluate whether animals are selecting for or against those environmental covariates. For this analysis, 10 available locations were generated for every used location. In the dataset these groups of 11 locations are clustered by their step_id_. The identity of each location i.e. whether they were a used (1) or available (0) location is represented in the caseN variable in the dataset.

The dataset also includes the environmental covariates of each location (medIncST, propWST, propPres1kmST, popDensST) and the animal's sex (Sex) and ID (id). The dataset is very large and it's hard to generate data needed reproduce the issue, so I've just included the first part of the data frame but I can include more data if need be.

```
    id step_id_ caseN  medIncST   propWST propPres1kmST  popDensST Sex
1 1086        2     1 -1.602343 0.1106249      1.672211 -0.3675946   m
2 1086        2     0 -1.602343 0.1106249      1.672211 -0.3675946   m
3 1086        2     0 -1.602343 0.1106249      1.672211 -0.3678993   m
4 1086        2     0 -1.602343 0.1106249      1.672211 -0.3678993   m
5 1086        2     0 -1.602343 0.1106249      1.672211 -0.3678993   m
6 1086        2     0 -1.602343 0.1106249      1.672211 -0.3675946   m
```

I ran following model:

```
fit <- glmmTMB::glmmTMB(caseN ~ medIncST + propWST + propPres1kmST + Sex + popDensST + (1|step_id_) + (0 + medIncST|id) + (0 + propWST|id) + (0 + propPres1kmST|id) + (0 + popDensST|id), data = data, family = poisson, start=list(theta=c(log(1e3), 0, 0, 0, 0)), map = list(theta=factor(c(NA, 1:4))))
```

Which gives me the following results:

```
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula:          caseN ~ medIncST + propWST + propPres1kmST + Sex + popDensST +  
    (1 | step_id_) + (0 + medIncST | id) + (0 + propWST | id) +  
    (0 + propPres1kmST | id) + (0 + popDensST | id)
Data: data

      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 788016.8  788126.3 -393998.4  787996.8    423118 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups   Name          Variance  Std.Dev. 
 step_id_ (Intercept)   1.000e+06 1000.0000
 id       medIncST      1.927e-01    0.4390
 id.1     propWST       3.967e-01    0.6298
 id.2     propPres1kmST 3.170e-01    0.5630
 id.3     popDensST     2.968e-01    0.5448
Number of obs: 423128, groups:  step_id_, 38635; id, 48

Conditional model:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -20.42888    2.84889  -7.171 7.45e-13 ***
medIncST       -0.02426    0.06954  -0.349    0.727    
propWST        -0.07522    0.09856  -0.763    0.445    
propPres1kmST   0.01595    0.10049   0.159    0.874    
Sexm            1.38777    3.26020   0.426    0.670    
popDensST      -1.10315    0.09125 -12.089  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Finally, I used ggpredict to plot the effect of popDensST on selection (i.e. caseN) and I get the following plot where the CI suggests there is an effect of popDensST, but the fit line does not.

```
plot(ggpredict(fit, terms = "popDensST"))
```

[image]

Any ideas on what might be happening here?

Comment: What are typical values of the covariates `medIncST`, etc?  If they aren't all close to zero, how do you propose to interpret this plot, in which they have all been set to zero?  BTW, where is the "flat line" of your title?  The plot has a clear pronounced spike at the left, seemingly consistent with the reported coefficient estimates.

Comment: The covariates are standardized so the means are equal to zero i.e. most of the values fall around zero. The spike is the confidence interval but the actual fit line (the thick black line at the bottom) is virtually flat.

Comment: I don't know what `ggpredict` purports to do, but it looks like plots the estimated *probability* against the variable.  If you instead plot the estimated *log odds,* that should clarify what's going on.  Also, the `step_id_` estimate is extraordinary. It suggests the model might not have converged to a reasonable solution. How did you choose your starting values?  What is the mean value of `caseN` in your dataset?

Comment: The y-axis should be the number of used locations, making it even weirder that it's not whole numbers. I fixed the variance of 1|step_id_ according to the recommendation in Muff et al. (J Anim Ecol. 2020;89:80–92.). The mean value of caseN is 1/11 since it is always the same number of used and available steps (1+10). That is, caseN is a dummy variable where the ratio of 1s to 0s is 1:10.